# How to set Text in popup box to particular text view in android?

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I have created two dynamic button and one dynamic text in my application.Now i want to change the text in the `TextView` when i click on button (edit).When i click on edit button then **popup box** will come and in that box i will insert some text and that text should be placed to the appropriate `TextView`. How can i do this? I have pasted my code.

public class CreateButton extends ActivityGroup implements View.OnClickListener
{
    int i=0,delet_id=0,tr_id=0,edit_id=0,no=1,tv_id=0,tg=1;
    TableLayout tl_bed,tl_kitchen,tl_living,tl_dining;
    TableRow tr;
    Button btn_delete,edit;
    TextView[] tv;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tl_bed = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutOfBed);

    Button Btn_BedRoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bed);
    Btn_BedRoom.setOnClickListener(ListenrOf_BedRoom);


}

// Listener Of Create Bed Room
private OnClickListener ListenrOf_BedRoom = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int no = 3;
        tv = new TextView[no];
        for(int i =0 ;i< no  ;i++){

        CreateRoom(i);
        }
    }
};

public void CreateRoom(int i)
{
    tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setId(tr_id);
    TableRow.LayoutParams Rdel = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Rdel.setMargins(45, 10, 0,0);

    Button btn_delete = new Button(this);

    btn_delete.setText("delete");
    btn_delete.setHeight(10);
    btn_delete.setWidth(10);
    btn_delete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close_btn);
    btn_delete.setLayoutParams(Rdel);
    btn_delete.setTag("DeleteTag");
    btn_delete.setId(delet_id);
    tr.addView(btn_delete);
    btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);

    Rdel.setMargins(15, 10, 0,0);
    Button edit = new Button(this);

    edit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_btn);
    edit.setHeight(10);
    edit.setWidth(10);
    edit.setLayoutParams(Rdel);
    edit.setTag("Edit Name");
    edit.setId(edit_id);
    tr.addView(edit);
    edit.setOnClickListener(this);

    TableRow.LayoutParams tr_text = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tr_text.setMargins(25, 5, 0,0);
    tv[i] = new TextView(this);

    tv[i].setLayoutParams(tr_text);
    tv[i].setId(tv_id);
   // tv.setTag("Change Text"+tg++);
    tv[i].setText("Bed Room"+no++);
    tv[i].setEnabled(true);

    tr.addView(tv[i]);

    tl_bed.addView(tr);

    delet_id++;
    tr_id++;
    edit_id++;
    tv_id++;
}

public void onClick(final View v) 
{
  final String tag = (String) v.getTag();
  final int z = v.getId();
  //Edit Click
  if (tag == "Edit Name") 
    {
        // prepare the alert box
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // set the message to display
        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
        // alertbox.setTitle("Hi Akshay"); // Gives Msg
        alertbox.setMessage("Edit Room Name"); // Gives Msg same as above

        final EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setId(edit_id++);
        final int a = et.getId();
        alertbox.setView(et);



        // add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click listener
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Save",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // click listener on the alert box
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // the button was clicked
                    final String s = et.getText().toString();
                        tv[z].setText(s);

                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                                            }
                });
        // show it
        alertbox.show();
    }

    if( tag == "DeleteTag") 
    {
        int tr = v.getId();
        tl_bed.removeView(findViewById(tr));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Room Deleted " +(tr+1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: where is ur code i cant see it ??

Comment: your code is not display here plz post it again..

Comment: @Pragna I have pasted my code

Comment: I have updated my class and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CreateButton extends ActivityGroup implements View.OnClickListener
{

int i=0;
TableLayout tl_bed;
TableRow tr;
Button btn_delete,edit;
TextView[] tv; // Here i have decleared an array of TextView


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tl_bed = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutOfBed);

    Button Btn_BedRoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bed);
    Btn_BedRoom.setOnClickListener(ListenrOf_BedRoom);      
}

// Listener Of Create Bed Room
private OnClickListener ListenrOf_BedRoom = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int no = 3;
        tv = new TextView[no];
        for(int i =0 ;i< no  ;i++){

        CreateRoom(i);
        }
    }
   };

   public void CreateRoom(int i)
{
    tr = new TableRow(this);
 // Here i have set the same id for deleting row and editing name.
    tr.setId(i);
    TableRow.LayoutParams Rdel = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Rdel.setMargins(45, 10, 0,0);

    Button btn_delete = new Button(this);

    btn_delete.setText("delete");
    btn_delete.setHeight(10);
    btn_delete.setWidth(10);
    btn_delete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close_btn);
    btn_delete.setLayoutParams(Rdel);
    btn_delete.setTag("DeleteTag");
    btn_delete.setId(i);
    tr.addView(btn_delete);
    btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);

    Rdel.setMargins(15, 10, 0,0);
    Button edit = new Button(this);

    edit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_btn);
    edit.setHeight(10);
    edit.setWidth(10);
    edit.setLayoutParams(Rdel);
         edit.setTag("Edit Name");
         edit.setId(i);
    tr.addView(edit);
    edit.setOnClickListener(this);

    TableRow.LayoutParams tr_text = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tr_text.setMargins(25, 5, 0,0);
    tv[i] = new TextView(this);

    tv[i].setLayoutParams(tr_text);
    tv[i].setId(i);
    tv[i].setText("Bed Room"+no++);
    tv[i].setEnabled(true);

    tr.addView(tv[i]);

    tl_bed.addView(tr);

  }

public void onClick(final View v) 
{
  final String tag = (String) v.getTag();
  final int z = v.getId();
  //Edit Click
  if (tag == "Edit Name") 
    {
        // prepare the alert box
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // set the message to display
        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
        // alertbox.setTitle("Hi Akshay"); // Gives Msg
        alertbox.setMessage("Edit Room Name"); // Gives Msg same as above

        final EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setId(edit_id++);
        final int a = et.getId();
        alertbox.setView(et);



        // add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click listener
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Save",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {

    // click listener on the alert box
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // the button was clicked
    final String s = et.getText().toString();
    tv[z].setText(s);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    }
                });
        // show it
        alertbox.show();
    }

    if( tag == "DeleteTag") 
    {
        int tr = v.getId();
        tl_bed.removeView(findViewById(tr));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Room Deleted " +(tr+1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}         
   }
```

This is my updated class and is working fine now.